# Howto Place cursor at beginning of textarea

Tags: javascript, prototype, textarea

I've found a couple resources for how to place the cursor in a textarea at the end of the text, but I can't sort out a simple way to make it appear at the beginning.

I'm prepopulating the textarea with some text and just want to make it easier on the users.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Pass a reference to your textarea to this JS function.

```
function resetCursor(txtElement) { 
    if (txtElement.setSelectionRange) { 
        txtElement.focus(); 
        txtElement.setSelectionRange(0, 0); 
    } else if (txtElement.createTextRange) { 
        var range = txtElement.createTextRange();  
        range.moveStart('character', 0); 
        range.select(); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Depending on your needs, a simpler Javascript version is:

```
document.querySelector("textarea").focus(); //set the focus - cursor at end
document.querySelector("textarea").setSelectionRange(0,0); // place cursor at start
```

You can't just string them together either, to get rid of the double querySelector - not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery way:

```
$('textarea[name="mytextarea"]').focus().setSelectionRange(0,0);
```

Comment: This won't work. Should be: `$('textarea[name="mytextarea"]').focus().get(0).setSelectionRange(0,0);` ... the added `get(0)` is to expose the DOM element since `setSelectionRange()` is a DOM method rather than a jQuery one.

Answer (score 0):

please, use for textarea with scroll after using `$(textareaSelector).val(val)`

```
$(textareaSelector)[0].setSelectionRange(0, 0);
$(textareaSelector).focus();
```

Answer (score -4):

Removed the spaces between the tags
like this:

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="extra"></textarea>
```