# Need cursor at beginning of text in textarea

Tags: javascript, textarea, text-cursor

I have this in my body and it works

```
onLoad='document.forms.post.message.focus()'
```

but I need the cursor to be placed in the `textarea` at the beginning of any existing text, not at the end. This puts it at the end.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Howto Place cursor at beginning of textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336585/howto-place-cursor-at-beginning-of-textarea)

Answer (score 11):

```
function moveCaretToStart(el) {
    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number") {
        el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = 0;
    } else if (typeof el.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        el.focus();
        var range = el.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.select();
    }
}

moveCaretToStart(document.forms["post"].elements["message"]);
```

Comment: I altered the method to take a location and created a plunker so users can try it out: https://plnkr.co/edit/YuCl18SiURfNxo3YKXAy?p=preview