# Can I position the cursor at the start of a textarea (HTA and VBScript)?

Tags: vbscript, hta

I have a `textarea` with some default text named `TextArea` like this:

```
<p><textarea name="TextArea">default text</textarea></p>
```

I set the focus to it using:

```
Sub Window_OnLoad
    TextArea.Focus
End Sub
```

Is there a way I can have the cursor at the start of `default text` rather than the end? I guess it has something to do with "SelStart" but I can't work out how to use it and google isn't helping.

Sorry if this is a basic question, it's my first real hta/vbscript and I'm learning as I go.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextArea.Focus` put the cursor at the beginning of the text when I tested it. You can move it using the [`SendKeys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method:

```
Sub Window_OnLoad
  TextArea.Focus
  CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys "^{Home}"
End Sub
```

The `SelStart` and `SelEnd` properties apply to textbox controls in Visual Basic forms, not to HTML `<textarea>` elements.

For more sophisticated cursor handling in textareas you probably [need JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1336630/1630171).

Comment: Thank you, does exactly what I wanted.